# Unable to remove the spaces from the text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

raw_text = """<div style="margin: 0 0 15px 0;">
                <b>Location:</b><br>


                        K23<br>

                    4225 Oaknoll Circle<br>Duluth, GA 30096

            </div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_text, "html.parser")
location_text = soup.find("b", text="Location:")
parent_location = location_text.parent
location_text_b_text = parent_location.find("b").extract()
location = parent_location.text.strip()
print("location: " + str(location))
```

Is there any solution to get the exact solution by removing spaces?

Required solution: `K23 4225 Oaknoll Circle Duluth, GA 30096`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After computing `parent_location`, try removing all leading and trailing spaces from each line, and filters out empty lines, and then concatenate the refined lines into a single string.

```
location_lines = [line.strip() for line in parent_location.text.splitlines() if line.strip()]
location = ' '.join(location_lines)
```